# water drainage and fence building

Tags: water, wood, drainage, fence, landscaping

I am a new homeowner and with the first summer coming up I am looking to do some renovation outside. The first thing I'd like to do is fence off my back yard so my dogs can roam instead of being walked or being on a lead. *ANYWAY* The rain drainage is looking like it's going to be an issue.

When it rains heavily, the water builds in the street and eventually fills my yard then drains to the ditch running vertically bordering the back half of my neighbors and my yard. It can sometimes build to a pond in my backyard before it eventually drains.

So I guess I'm just asking for general fencing or landscaping solutions. My back yard does have a slope downward to the drainage ditch toward the back but other than that it is the same elevation (from what I can tell) from the front to approx. the back fence area of the neighboring fences.

I would like to have privacy fencing connecting to the neighbors fencing and along a similar fence line that they have. But I don't know how practical it is for water pooling and constant draining.  I figured the only solution was to have the privacy fencing on either side and have chain-link across the back. But that's a face value, non-knowing homeowner assessment on a solution.
[image: I attached a picture vaguely illustrating the layout from the main road to back yard and wild area behind the houses as well.]

Comment: Unless you have the pickets of the fence coming all the way down to the ground, they won't really impact water drainage. If you do have the pickets coming all the way down to the ground, plan on replacing them after just a couple of years because they'll rot out. You need to work on drainage first (the fence will likely be in the way of the drainage project), then the fence.

Comment: Would contact the local(town/city) government.  Most places have storm drains or drainage ditches for the road so the water from the road does flow over peoples yards.  Should have a gentle slope on all 4 sides of the house.

Comment: I didn't understand the description or the picture completely, but in general you could consider creating one or more swales to encourage the water to flow in the direction you want.  Does the ditch you mentioned ever overflow?  If a local university has a landscape design department, you could invite an instructor or advanced student to come look at your situation.